# How does one talk about comparing positions of characters in a string?

Tags: python

For example, let's say I've assigned integer values to A, B, and C, like so:

```
def values(char):
    if char == 'A':
        val = 1
    if char == 'B':
        val = 2
    if char == 'C':
        val = 3
    return value
```

Now I have another function that is used to give me the value of a string with the characters A, B, and C. If the character is less than the character to its left, the total value would decrease. Otherwise, the value would continue to increase.

I had a for loop:

```
for c in abcstring[1:]:
   if values(c) < values(c-1)
```

But then it didn't work and I remembered it's because c is still a letter from the string, and you can't subtract 1 from a letter. How, then, do I specify that I want the value of the character to the left of c?

Comment: Maybe try a dictionary to hold the mapping - ```{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}```

Comment: @keyser based on my reading the OP wants to get a number from a letter, which seems to match what wwii was demonstrating (and is why I answered the way I did)

Comment: @Dannnno Yes of course, since OP wants to compare them as ints that's true. What I meant was that the other way around was needed to jump freely between letters as indexes.That's not what OP needed though, and the `previous` code sufficed.

Comment: @keyser, I don't think those are indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you could simplify your `values` function to get rid of the if statements by using a dictionary.  Also, your function won't work because you're assigning `val = some number` but then you `return value`.

```
char_dict = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}

def values(char):
    return char_dict[char]
```

Here are two ways to refer to the previous character. The first would be to keep track of it.

```
previous = abcstring[0]

for c in abcstring[1:]:
    if values(c) < values(previous):
        do_something()
    previous = c
```

Or you could use a range instead.

```
for i in range(1, len(abcstring)):
    c = abcstring[i]
    previous = abcstring[i-1]
    if values(c) < values(previous):
        do_something()
```

You could also use an enumeration, as pointed out in the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

To keep track of an index while iterating, you can use enumerate!

```
for index,c in enumerate(abcstring[1:]):
    if values(c) < values(abscstring[index-1]):
        ...
```

Or, to save you the slice, you could even use the `start` parameter:

```
for index,c in enumerate(abcstring, start=1):
    if values(c) < values(abscstring[index-1]):
        ...
```

Which is slightly more verbose, but perhaps more clear.